# MVC url to image inside area

Tags: image, model-view-controller, resources, png

If i have the following structure in an MVC site.

```
Areas
  + Documents
    + Controllers
    + Models
    + Views
      + Shared
        + icons
            icon.png
```

I am trying to use `img src='@url.Content("~/Areas/Documents/Views/Shared/icons/icon.png")'`/>

Why is this image unavailable?
Is there another path to use? Weird that I can browse to the file path in firefox, but as soon as I click on the image it errors with resource unavailable.

Do images have to go into the content directory?

Regards

Craig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I don't know how to override that as default the css and images has to go to the Content folder.

**UPDATED**: I correct what I said above, the images cannot be inside the Views\Shared folder without any special coding. You have to put the images in the outside folder but the folder can be named any instead of "Content".

Comment: This seems to be the case. Do you know what routing changes need to be made to be able to serve images from other directories?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

img src='@Url.Content("../../Content/Images/6.jpg")' alt="" style="width: 100px; height: 100px" />

Yet my problem is getting the corresponding image to the product I am trying to show, no luck so far, I have tried hard coding too.

Answer (score 0):

The Shared folder in MVC is used as a default location for views.  When your routing request is rendered the process will check the Controller's view folder for the correct view, if it is not present, the it will check the Shared folder for the view.

There is nothing stopping you from putting an image in your Views folder or any folder in your structure, but it usually not the norm.  Check to see that the image is referenced correctly.  Right click and check the properties of the image.  Check to see if the path is being rendered properly to find the image.

Comment: Have you tried putting images in the Shared folder? Are you done any additional routing?